# Django ManyToMany Field with an already existing table

Tags: python, django, oracle, django-models

What I'm trying to achieve is, having model `Person` that is created and managed by Django have a ManyToMany field with model `Property` that was "created" using inspectdb and already exists in the database.

(`Property` contains Geographical data and cannot be managed or changed by Django)

When trying to migrate, it raises :

> ValueError: Related model 'cadastroapp.Property' cannot be resolved

[Full stack here](http://pastebin.com/AkhU2Cwq)

Worth nothing that I removed from the migration file the step to create model `Property`, since it already exists and AFAIK there's no way to tell Django this in the model Class

models.py (simplified) :

```
class Person(models.Model):
    objectid = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    properties = models.ManyToManyField(
        'Property', 
        through = 'Person_Property',
        )
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'django_person'

class Person_Property(models.Model):
    cod_person = models.ForeignKey('Person', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    cod_property = models.ForeignKey('Property', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'django_person_property'

class Property(models.Model):
    objectid = models.BigIntegerField(unique=True, primary_key=True)
    created_user = models.CharField(max_length=765, blank=True, null=True)
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    last_edited_user = models.CharField(max_length=765, blank=True, null=True)
    last_edited_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    shape = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)  # This field type is a guess. - ESRI Shape

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = '"GEO"."PROPERTY"'
```

Comment: Please post the migration file cadastroapp.0006_auto_20161122_1533

Comment: @PatrickFalvey here http://pastebin.com/Nv49Kwep

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple errors in your models.py file.
When defining a Foreignkey or ManytoMany field, you don't want the model name to be in quotes.

Please change:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    properties = models.ManyToManyField(
        'Property', 
        through = 'Person_Property',
        )
```

and

```
class Person_Property(models.Model):
    cod_person = models.ForeignKey('Person', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    cod_property = models.ForeignKey('Property', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

to:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    properties = models.ManyToManyField(
        Property, 
        through = 'Person_Property',
        )
```

and

```
class Person_Property(models.Model):
    cod_person = models.ForeignKey(Person, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    cod_property = models.ForeignKey(Property, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

then delete your migration file cadastroapp.0006_auto_20161122_1533.
then run makemigrations and migrate again.

This may still not migrate without errors, but it will get us on the right track.

Comment: Even removing the lazy references the error still applies, I believe it is due to the fact that I manually removed the bit that creates Poperty model in the migration, but if I don't remove it it will just raise an ORA error that table already exists

Comment: If all `migrations.CreateModel` does is create the table, I guess I could just create them all manually and do a fake migration, not sure though

Comment: I have already an intermediate table created and it's in use in production. Now I want to use `through` to add extra fields. 

When I did this, I am getting this error.

"Field specifies a many-to-many relation through model 'Photo_Tag', which has not been installed."

thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

I think that you want to put the model name in quotes. In case you leave it without quotes you have to ensure that the model is defined before the ManyToMany field has been defined. So you will need to have first class Property and then class Person in your file. When you put model name as "Property" then you do not need to care about order of class definitions.

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.